# How to access and display specific list item in flask

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

Like in python we can able to access element of the list by mentioning its position , can we do that similar thing in flask

**Example**
*main.py*

```
def line():
    list=[1,2,3,4,5]
    return render_template('list.html',list=list)
```

*list.html*

```
{% for item in list %}
  <li>{{item}} </li>
{% endfor %}
```

As we know the above line will print entire list.
But can we print only the item of list , that's is in the 2nd position

something like this:

```
{% for item in list %}
      <li>{{item[2]}} </li>
 {% endfor %}
```

should only display:

```
3
```

Do you have any ideas?? how to do to it in flask using Jinja template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is your answer

```
<li>{{list[2]}}</li>
```

No need to print the whole list if you don't want to, just pass the index.

Answer (score 1):

First, you're displaying it in Jinja and not Flask

With respect to your specific question, did you try your solution and it didn't work? `{{item[2]}}` should work or you can try `{{item.2.<property_name>}}`